# No laser scan received

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, ros-kinetic, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know this question has been asked many times for single robot but i cannot figure it out for my multi-robot-system.
Please Note: It is perfectly working for a single robot. But it is giving the error below when launching multiple robots.

```
    No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 18.505000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /plato1/scan topic.
[ WARN] [1544187859.336072043, 18.505000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1544187859.350568657, 18.515000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 18.515000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /plato2/scan topic.
[ WARN] [1544187859.350708006, 18.515000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

Now, the problem is that data is being **published** on the topics (**/plato1/scan** and **/plato2/scan**). But somehow this error is causing me problems.

I am running it in Gazebo simulation.

(((Below is the pdf file of the tf tree. Please download it)))
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmvqfK5s28ZUOdPCQh_UPQeKk3x6D-9k/view?usp=sharing

Any help please!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310223/no-laser-scan-received/) by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-07**:
Can you tell us more about your setup. Are you using multiple on board computers? Have you checking messages can be passed between them okay? What does rqt_graph show on each machine?

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-12-08**:
@pete Well, it is in simulation (gazebo). So, it is working.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
The most imortant thing is actually `MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far.`. This is from `tf`, which is used to transform the laserscan into the map frame. As this is simulation, I'm assuming you are running this on a single computer. Have you checked the `tf` setup? ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
You need to have seperate trees for both robots. This is hard to achieve, and since `tf2` [removed `tf_prefix` support](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration#Removal_of_support_for_tf_prefix) it is even harder to achieve now. Though it wasn't super easy to begin with...
...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
to go further in debugging, please post a picture of your tf tree, e.g. using `rosrun tf view_frames`.

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-12-10**:
@mgruhler I have attached the tf tree in pdf format. You need to edit the extension (remove **.jpg** to view pdf).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
@RoboRos when you edit the question, you can embedd it by clicking on the "image" link above the edit window. I can't access the image the way you integrated it.

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-12-10**:
You can download the file from the below link: (image wont be able to present the whole tree):
.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmvqfK5s28ZUOdPCQh_UPQeKk3x6D-9k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, having this as an embedded image would be nicer. But given the width of it, I see your problem ;-)

My guess is the problem comes from the SLAM (whatever it may be) actually looking for the frame `odom`, whereas it should look for `plato1/odom`. You would need to adapt the config of the SLAM, if it has something like an `odom_frame` parameter. If it is hard-coded (what I've seen some times), you might have to change the source code...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-12-11**:
yup, yup, solved. Thanks for your help.
I was not providing proper (frames or parameters) to amcl.

**Comment by [aryanna003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40384/aryanna003/) on 2019-03-21**:
i'm the same problem, what have you changed?
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2019-03-21**:
The same Problem? Well, i was not providing the correct topics (or call it name space). You need to pass the correct namespace forexample: for single robot the topic can be: /odom...   but for multiple robots it is: /robot1/odom .... /robot2/odom and so on.....

**Comment by [aryanna003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40384/aryanna003/) on 2019-03-22**:
my name topic are correct.. :-( the topic to subscribe is :
/scan
/odom
/tf
is corretc?

**Comment by [aryanna003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40384/aryanna003/) on 2019-03-22**:
Pid: 25146
Connections:

- topic: /rosout

  - to: /rosout
  - direction: outbound
  - transport: TCPROS
- topic: /tf

  - to: /amcl
  - direction: outbound
  - transport: INTRAPROCESS
- topic: /tf

  - to: /amcl (http://arianna-MSI:44209/)
  - direction: inbound
  - transport: INTRAPROCESS
- topic: /tf

  - to: /odometry_publisher (http://arianna-MSI:33259/)
  - direction: inbound
  - transport: TCPROS
- topic: /tf_static

  - to: /camera/realsense2_camera_manager (http://arianna-MSI:37699/)
  - direction: inbound
  - transport: TCPROS
- topic: /scan

  - to: /laser_scan_publisher (http://arianna-MSI:37603/)
  - direction: inbound
  - transport: TCPRO

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-22**:
@aryanna003 if the above does not directly solve your problem, it might be beneficial if you create a new question with all the respective information. This way, more people will actually see it...

**Comment by [aryanna003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40384/aryanna003/) on 2019-03-22**:
i'have create it
https://answers.ros.org/question/319122/amcl-no-laser-scan-receved/